# How do I find which image field in PDF has image inserted and which one has no images attached using PDFbox 1.8.11?

Tags: itext, pdfbox

I have a PDF that has image fields inside it. I am not using a PDPushButton with javascript  to attach pictures because if I do that the button's top layer gets replaced with the picture that I am attaching which is not what I want. So I am explicitly using a ImageField that is available in Adobe LiveCycle Designer.  I am able to extract the files attached on it using PDFBox but I am not able to find any way of seeing which image fields have files attached to them and which ones do not. For example if I have the following code here:

ImageField[1], ImageField[2], ImageField[3]

I want to see something like
ImageField[1]: null,
ImageField[2]: true,
ImageField[3]: true`enter code here`

etc assuming ImageField[2] and ImageField[3] has images attached to them.

Below is the code that I was working on:

I have a constant:

Then I am looping through the whole set of  image field names and see which field is a instance of PDXObjectImage and then if it is a PDXObjectImage then I check if that object.getRGBImage().getHeight() > 0 assuming that only files uploaded have a height > 1 which means a file has been attached.

private static String[] IMAGE_FIELD_ROW = {"ImageField1[0]","ImageField2[0]",....}  => 100 rows of string values such as "ImageField3[0]", "ImageField4[0]", ...etc.

```
    for(int i = 0; i<IMAGE_FIELD_ROW.length; i++)
    {
        if(field.getPartialName().equals(IMAGE_FIELD_ROW[i]))
        {
            Map<String, PDAppearanceStream> stateAppearances = field.getWidget().getAppearance().getNormalAppearance();
            for (Map.Entry<String, PDAppearanceStream> entry: stateAppearances.entrySet())
            {
                PDAppearanceStream appearance = entry.getValue();
                PDResources resources = appearance.getResources();
                 if (resources == null)
                     return;
                 Map<String, PDXObject> xObjects = resources.getXObjects();
                 if (xObjects == null)
                     return;

                 for (Map.Entry<String, PDXObject> entryNew : xObjects.entrySet())
                 {
                     PDXObject xObject = entryNew.getValue();
                     System.out.println("printing out the xobject name: "+ entryNew.getKey());


                     if (xObject instanceof PDXObjectForm)
                     {

                         PDXObjectForm form = (PDXObjectForm)xObject;
                         PDResources resources2 = form.getResources();
                         if (resources2 == null)
                             return;
                         Map<String, PDXObject> xObjects2 = resources2.getXObjects();
                         if (xObjects2 == null)
                         {
                             return;
                         }
                         for (Map.Entry<String, PDXObject> entry2 : xObjects2.entrySet())
                         {

                             PDXObject xObject2 = entry2.getValue();

                             if (xObject2 instanceof PDXObjectForm)
                             {
                                 continue;
                             }
                             else if (xObject2 instanceof PDXObjectImage)
                             {
                                 PDXObjectImage ig = (PDXObjectImage)xObject2;
                                 if(ig.getRGBImage().getHeight() >  0)
                                 {
                                     images.put(field.getPartialName(), "true");
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                     images.put(field.getPartialName(), null);
                                 }

                                 //imageIds.add(imageId);
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                continue;
                             }

                     }

                 }
            }

        }
        }
    }
```

Images is a map variable: Mapimages.

Also my code file is large and so I didn't want to overwhelm anybody by pasting the whole file. Below is the dropbox link for the sample PDF file that I am using:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g2wqm8ipsp8t8l5/GSA%20500%20PDF_v4.pdf?dl=0

Comment: The current 1.8 version is 1.8.16. Please edit your question to show the code you are using and share the PDF. Also clarify: is your question about *images* attached, or *files* attached? It is confusing because you mention "I am able to extract the images attachhed on it" and also "How do I find which image field in PDF has image inserted".

Comment: You mention image *fields*. Please be aware that the pdf format does not know image fields. Some pdf creators use push buttons in combination with javascript to *emulate* image fields. But since those still are push buttons, they don't have a *value*, merely an *appearance* into which an image may be integrated.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr: I am looking to  attach images on this PDF. I have updated the description of the question with sample code and more description. Hope that helps.

Comment: Please share an example PDF. *"Currently there is no way of attaching the PDF on this question as stackoverflow doesn't allow it"* - Usually PDFs are shared on some file sharing service (e.g. as public shares on google drive or dropbox; please don't use a service that drowns the downloader in spam), then the download URL is added here.

Comment: @mkl I have pasted a dropbox link of a sample PDF

Comment: I don't have much time right now, but I recommend you get the latest version of PDFDebugger and then look at the annotations... Root/Pages/Kids/[2]/Kids/[0]/Annots/[12]/AP/N  does not have an image, while Root/Pages/Kids/[2]/Kids/[0]/Annots/[0]/AP/N/Resources/XObject/FRM/Resources/XObject/Im0 does have one. If all your files have the same structure, then you could work with the differences.

Comment: Ok, having had a look at the PDF, your claim *"I am not using a PDPushButton with javascript to attach pictures"* is a bit misleading. Your PDF is a hybrid AcroForm/XFA document and where the XFA part uses fields with an `imageEdit` user interface, the AcroForm part uses pushbutton fields. There merely is no JavaScript in the AcroForm to allow changing the image. This document allows you two ways to check whether an image field is set. Either you look at the AcroForm buttons and inspect their appearances for images, or you retrieve the XFA XML and inspect that.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Is there a better way to traverse through this path Root/Pages/Kids/[2]/Kids/[0]/Annots/[0]/AP/N/Resources/XObject/FRM/Resources/XObject/Im0.....I tried doing page.getAnnotations().get(index).getCOSObject(). Then I did COSBase apDictionary = ((COSDictionary)base).getItem(COSName.AP) and then for N I did COSBase nDict = ((COSDictionary)apDictionary).getItem(COSName.N)...etc but when I reach resources..it doesn't allow to do COSDictionary again and I am stuck

Comment: PDResources should have a getCOSObject() and/or getDictionary() method which gives a dictionary. If you have a COSObject then call getObject() on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PDF is a hybrid AcroForm/XFA document; where the XFA part uses fields with an imageEdit user interface, the AcroForm part uses pushbutton fields.

Thus, it allows you two ways to check whether an image field is set: Either you look at the AcroForm buttons and inspect their appearances for images, or you retrieve the XFA XML and inspect that.

#### Checking the XFA XML

*Initially I did overlook the PDFBox version in the question title and implemented this for PDFBox 2.0.x. As it turns out, though, the identical code can be used for PDFBox 1.8.11, merely some additional exceptions may be thrown and, therefore, must be considered.*

The latter option, inspecting the XFA XML, actually is a bit easier for the document at hand. Simply search the XML for an element with the name in question and check its contents. As an additional sanity check one can verify the content type attribute of the element:

```
boolean isFieldFilledXfa(Document xfaDom, String fieldName) {
    NodeList fieldElements = xfaDom.getElementsByTagName(fieldName);
    for (int i = 0; i < fieldElements.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = fieldElements.item(i);
        if (node instanceof Element) {
            Element element = (Element) node;
            if (element.getAttribute("xfa:contentType").startsWith("image/")) {
                return element.getTextContent().length() > 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

*([CheckImageFieldFilled](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/form/CheckImageFieldFilled.java#L66) helper method)*

With it you can check your document:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(SOURCE);
PDAcroForm acroForm = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
Document xfaDom = acroForm.getXFA().getDocument();

System.out.println("Filled image fields from ImageField1..ImageField105:");
for (int i=1; i < 106; i++) {
    if (isFieldFilledXfa(xfaDom, "ImageField" + i)) {
        System.out.printf("* ImageField%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

*([CheckImageFieldFilled](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/form/CheckImageFieldFilled.java#L50) test method `testCheckXfaGsa500Pdf_v4`)*

The output:

```
Filled image fields from ImageField1..ImageField105:
* ImageField1
* ImageField3
* ImageField6
```

#### Checking the AcroForm Appearances

*The implementation here only works as is for PDFBox 2.0.x. The structure of the content stream parser classes has been considerably overhauled in 2.0.0, making a back-port of this code to 1.8.x a bit tedious.*

To check whether the push button appearance actually *shows* an image (and not only has an image *in its resources*), one can use a simple `PDFGraphicsStreamEngine` subclass like this:

```
public class WidgetImageChecker extends PDFGraphicsStreamEngine
{
    public WidgetImageChecker(PDAnnotationWidget widget) {
        super(widget.getPage());
        this.widget = widget;
    }

    public boolean hasImages() throws IOException {
        count = 0;
        PDAppearanceStream normalAppearance = widget.getNormalAppearanceStream();
        processChildStream(normalAppearance, widget.getPage());
        return count != 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void drawImage(PDImage pdImage) throws IOException {
        count++;
    }

    @Override
    public void appendRectangle(Point2D p0, Point2D p1, Point2D p2, Point2D p3) throws IOException { }

    @Override
    public void clip(int windingRule) throws IOException { }

    @Override
    public void moveTo(float x, float y) throws IOException {  }

    @Override
    public void lineTo(float x, float y) throws IOException { }

    @Override
    public void curveTo(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3) throws IOException {  }

    @Override
    public Point2D getCurrentPoint() throws IOException { return null; }

    @Override
    public void closePath() throws IOException { }

    @Override
    public void endPath() throws IOException { }

    @Override
    public void strokePath() throws IOException { }

    @Override
    public void fillPath(int windingRule) throws IOException { }

    @Override
    public void fillAndStrokePath(int windingRule) throws IOException { }

    @Override
    public void shadingFill(COSName shadingName) throws IOException { }

    final PDAnnotationWidget widget;
    int count = 0;
}
```

*([CheckImageFieldFilled](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/form/CheckImageFieldFilled.java#L123) helper class)*

With it you can create a check method like this:

```
boolean isFieldFilledAcroForm(PDAcroForm acroForm, String fieldName) throws IOException {
    for (PDField field : acroForm.getFieldTree()) {
        if (field instanceof PDPushButton && fieldName.equals(field.getPartialName())) {
            for (final PDAnnotationWidget widget : field.getWidgets()) {
                WidgetImageChecker checker = new WidgetImageChecker(widget);
                if (checker.hasImages())
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

*([CheckImageFieldFilled](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/form/CheckImageFieldFilled.java#L110) helper method)*

and use it like this:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(SOURCE);
PDAcroForm acroForm = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();

System.out.println("Filled image fields (AcroForm) from ImageField1..ImageField105:");
for (int i=1; i < 106; i++) {
    if (isFieldFilledAcroForm(acroForm, "ImageField" + i + "[0]")) {
        System.out.printf("* ImageField%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

*([CheckImageFieldFilled](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/form/CheckImageFieldFilled.java#L95) test `testCheckAcroFormGsa500Pdf_v4`)*

The output, just like above:

```
Filled image fields (AcroForm) from ImageField1..ImageField105:
* ImageField1
* ImageField3
* ImageField6
```